# Using Android Studio and Eclipse simultaneously

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am starting on my senior project for my school and I am building an Android Application. I was thinking of using the Android Studio IDE however on the school computers, they still have only Eclipse. I was wondering if using both at the same time would work? If not I will just use my laptop for Android Studio.

Comment: None of the standard Eclipse downloads knows anything about Android.

Comment: a full import of eclipse project to android studio project is possible easily but from android studio project to eclipse is not that easy as you have to do manual copy paste and then build it. I think you should just stick to one IDE.

Comment: can't you simply download android studio at school ?

Comment: Android studio is in beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (easily) use both for the same project, without introducing a lot of headaches. It is possible to "import" an Eclipse based android project into Android Studio, but not the other way around, because Google wants to move from Eclipse to AS. 
Strictly speaking both ways is doable, but not worth the effort. There is no advantage with Android Studio unless you are using it for the (in my opinion) better build system - gradle. Also, the UI Designer is better, but I am used to hand-code the UI so I don't care much for that.

From your question, it looks like you are doing a project for school - it is better to stick to whatever is used in the school (Eclipse in this case) - that way you can put your efforts into learning the Android framework rather than the tools!
BTW, Eclipse+ADT has been and still in use for majority of the Android dev going on. Most large-scale projects cannot even move to AS without starting from scratch. Eclipse+ADT is pretty much fine for development, ignoring occassional hiccups.

Answer (score 0):

The build systems between the eclipse environment and Android Studio environment are different so keeping the projects in sync could be challenging as you make changes in one environment and then switch to the other.  In addition, at the time of this writing, Android Studio beta v0.8.x does not support the Android NDK so if you plan to use or develop any native libraries, eclipse may be better suited for your project.  If you are developing only Java code, Android Studio is pretty stable now and is a good choice for development.